# GC overhead limit exceeded when calling external Python process

Tags: java, python, process

I have a java program which calls a python script `script.py`as follows

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 /home/user/script.py " + id + " " + text);
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getErrorStream()));
String s;
StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
boolean isT = false;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    isT = true;
    t.append(s);
}
if (isT) {
    stdInput.close();
    stdError.close();
    p1.destroy();
    return t.toString();
}
logger.info(text);
StringBuilder error_text = new StringBuilder();
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    error_text.append(s);
}
logger.info(error_text.toString());
stdInput.close();
stdError.close();
p1.destroy();
return text;
```

This segment of code is called in a loop, whenever some condition is met. I am getting the output from python and collecting it using `p1.getInputStream()`.

The python script is as follows

```
import sys
text = ''
id_ = sys.argv[1]

for w in sys.argv[2:]:
    text += w + ' '

text = text.replace('\n', ' ')

list_ = [text]
ret_val = my_function(list_)
with open('/home/user/output.txt', 'a') as out:
    for r in ret_val:
        print(r)
        out.write(id_ + '\t\t' + r + '\n')
```

The script works fine at the beginning but as time proceeds I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:669)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:359)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.newNode(LinkedHashMap.java:256)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:631)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    ...
```

Even after this the python script is called repeatedly and everything is working fine but after some more time I keep getting the error as follows

```
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "..." java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
...
```

and my python script stops responding.

I have tried to stop the inputstreamreaders by using `stdInput.close()` and `stdError.close()` and i am killing the process by using `p1.destroy()`, but I think that this is not destroying the sub-processes or is there something else I am missing, what other ways can I achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you have an memory leak somewhere else in your code, and that the read loop is highlighted because it requires the most memory in short bursts

Comment: What do you do with data when it's returned?

Comment: @Ferrybig if I dont call the python script, I dont get this error

Comment: @PavelSmirnov i store it in mongoDb, I am using flume which does this and is setup in java, so I cant do that using python itself.

Comment: If your editor has a profile function, start your program using the memory profiler, most profilers will offer to make an snapshot of the memory when the program crashes. ( Can't link to tutorial of this as I'm on mobile)

Comment: Well, you deifinitely have a memory leak. My guess it's somewhere outside the function, probably, the data the function returns is never erased. Try inspecting your memory with a profiler as @Ferrybig suggested. Also, you may provide us the rest of the code, so we can see where the data goes to.